# What are the success exit codes from tSQLt

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, tsqlt

I am trying to integrate tSQLt / SQLTest with CruiseControl.NET
My tests are running and I've written xsl files to display the results but I need to know how to mark the build as failed if any tests fail.

My CCNet exec is:

```
<exec executable="$(sqlCmdPath)">
    <description>Run Unit Tests</description>
    <buildArgs>-E -d MyDatabase 
       -i "\CruiseControlProjects\Configuration\CI_SQL\RunTests.sql"
    </buildArgs>
    <baseDirectory>\Artifacts\MyDatabase</baseDirectory>
    <successExitCodes>0,63</successExitCodes>
</exec>
```

RunTests.sql:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[tSQLt].[RunAll]')
AND TYPE IN (N'P',N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXECUTE [tSQLt].[RunAll]
END
```

The tests are run and I have a subsequent task which produces the results in xml that are then merged into the build log:

```
<exec executable="$(sqlCmdPath)">
    <description>Get Unit Tests</description>
    <buildArgs>-E -b -d MyDatabase -h-1 -y0 -I 
       -i "\CruiseControlProjects\Configuration\CI_SQL\GetTestResults.sql" 
       -o "\CruiseControlProjects\Configuration\CI_SQL\Results\TestResults.xml"
    </buildArgs>
    <baseDirectory>\Artifacts\MDatabase</baseDirectory>
    <successExitCodes>0,63</successExitCodes>
</exec>
```

So how do I get the overall build to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the -b parameter to [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx), you should find that it will throw an error with a non-zero code when the batch fails (which will happen if tSQLt fails at least one test).

However, I have one potential suggestion to explore. If you can load the XML file within Cruise Control, then the tests can be loaded in as the XML file is in the same format as an nUnit test output file. (Note - I've used this method on [TeamCity](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/using-sql-test-database-unit-testing-with-teamcity-continuous-integration/) and Jenkins, but not tried with Cruise Control). This will treat the tests as tests rather than an 'all-or-nothing' approach, and enabling you to track which tests fail repeatedly.

Hope that helps,

Dave.

Comment: Specifically w.r.t. the error code, from the MSDN page linked above - "The value that is returned to the DOS ERRORLEVEL variable is 1 when the SQL Server error message has a severity level greater than 10; otherwise, the value returned is 0. .... Command prompt batch files can test the value of ERRORLEVEL and handle the error appropriately. sqlcmd does not report errors for severity level 10 (informational messages).

If the sqlcmd script contains an incorrect comment, syntax error, or is missing a scripting variable, ERRORLEVEL returned is 1."

Comment: With the -b parameter in the Run Unit test step, if any test fails then the whole build is aborted, which means there's no xml created and no merge happens. So I've pulled the parameter back out again and the xml is created and merged, but the build says it is successful when there are 2 failing tests

Comment: I am merging the XML that's generated (when there's no -b parameter), I needed to tweak the NUnit XSL file as the structure is slightly different, but can see the results in the build log and in a custom BuildReportPlugin I had to create. When you say the tests can be loaded in to Cruise Control is that what you meant?

Comment: Essentially, yes that's what I meant. I'm not familiar with Cruise Control in detail (as I noted above I am more used to other CI systems). That said, if you want the build to run all tests, but only then mark as failure you could try something similar to the process outlined [here] (http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Using+CruiseControl.NET+with+NUnit). Running the tests as you are I think is similar to running nUnit as the above link is working. You can then load in the results as they do. Note the failure test is then moved outside of the exec section.

Comment: Unfortunately the native CCNet build syntax (i.e. Not NAnt) doesn't provide, as far as I can see, an option for fail that I could use http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Configuring_the_server_(ccnetconfig). Because the exec task just runs sql command, rather than a bespoke tsqlt task (as there are nunit / ncover task blocks) perhaps there isn't a success / error code?

Comment: I see your point. Here's an alternative idea, based on [this post by tSQLt author Dennis](http://tsqlt.org/177/integrating-tsqlt-with-cruise-control/) - Why not have a third step which checks the content of the test results, running something akin to `sqlcmd -b -d MyDatabase -Q "IF EXISTS (select * from tSQLt.TestResult where Result != 'Success') RAISERROR ('Errors encountered',16,1)"` - this would then error (errorlevel=1) if tests had failed or errored, but I believe not prevent the output being produced and merged into the build output. If no failures are found, errorlevel=0.